# Mongo 2.4 - making db object available in server-side code (map/reduce)

Tags: mongodb

We started using Mongo at 2.0. As part of the queries that we frequently run, we run map/reduce jobs that also pull data from other collections as these jobs execute.

Since mongo 2.4, this functionality was removed (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#additional-limitations-for-map-reduce-and-where-operations), with the only suggestion of "refactor your code".

So, is there a way to refactor the code? I know it's a general question, but I am asking for a general application. The size and use of involved collections and cross-queries has enough variety.

At this point, I would even take a patch that just brings the `db` object back into the server code scope. It seems that the following patch is sufficient (yes, I understand it has these security implications, but I'm not even using shards. It's the quickest way for us to regain the functionality that we depend on):

```
diff --git a/src/mongo/db/commands/mr.cpp b/src/mongo/db/commands/mr.cpp
index 742392f..225a2b7 100644
--- a/src/mongo/db/commands/mr.cpp
+++ b/src/mongo/db/commands/mr.cpp
@@ -623,6 +623,7 @@ namespace mongo {
         void State::init() {
             // setup js
             _scope.reset(globalScriptEngine->getPooledScope( _config.dbname, "mapreduce" ).release() );
+            _scope->localConnect( _config.dbname.c_str() );

             if ( ! _config.scopeSetup.isEmpty() )
                 _scope->init( &_config.scopeSetup );
```

Comment: The problem is that due to how the db object ran in sharded envos this functionality was actually a security flaw and could have been used to bypass auth on other databases to attack your data. As to how to refactor your code; what exactly are you doing in the MR? Can you give us some logic?

Comment: @Sammaye Don't get me started on this "security" thing. It was not a fix, it's an obvious plug-the-hole solution, instead of properly redesigning/fixing the security architecture. I know that I can always refactor my queries to either pre-join the data on the client side, or pre-load the data into the server scope. But I don't want to, and there is a large performance price.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, MapReduce only operates on the input document set and emitted values.  Performing a DB operation is outside the scope of a MapReduce job, strictly speaking.  For more information on why this change was made, please see [SERVER-8104](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8104) and [SERVER-3130](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3130).

With that said, the supplied patch should work, but I would caution against using it due to locking implications (and aforementioned security issues).

As for the generalized question of how to refactor code which may have utilized this feature in past versions, one suggestion that comes to mind is using multiple MapReduce jobs which leverage the 'reduce' output type.  The documentation for [incremental MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-incremental-map-reduce/) may be helpful here.

If the goal is server-side execution, another option may be to refactor the MapReduce logic into a script which can be executed using [db.eval()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/).  This may be a somewhat complex exercise due to the nature of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for validating the patch. In my case, at least in some of them, it's really not possible to use map-reduce based joins (same as incremental approach). The join look up can reduce a key space from millions of values to a handful. I don't believe there is much difference in lock use between looking a key up up inside the `map` function, or the client side.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're describing the need to join 2 collections.  I've done this in the past with success and wrote up an example that includes test data from data.gov and cia.gov here:

http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/

There are 2 main things to be aware of with this approach:

1. Your join condition between the collections will need to be the emitted key.
2. The shape of the documents being emitted should be the same.

Then it is just a matter of combining the emitted documents in your reducer.  Doing it this way should scale well across shards and possibly even locally across cores (see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4258).

Comment: It's a nice trick, I wasn't ever considering it. When I had to do plain joins like that, I would still use client-side joins. However, it's not possible to join by key in all of my applications of m/r.

Comment: @PawelVeselov The problem with this is that you are doing untamed lookups in both tables then just merging the output of the two MRs into one collection, you are not actually doing a join and will not get any of the benefits of a confined dataset

Comment: @Sammaye The big power of map reduce is that the mapping function can pin to precise keys that you need in the output. The functions to derive these keys can be quite complex and elaborate. But sometimes (also @vrtx) the functions just can't be coded and has to be a lookup into some external datasource. I see that lookup ability as just a logical extension to any other function use.

Comment: @PawelVeselov What I was trying to say was the method suggested does not provide the same functionality as you previously had. It requires running two individual map reduces and then merging the output from one mr to the other in a collection, it won't provide the data from external data source that you require within the processing of the MR

Answer (score 0):

I know old questions, logging it here for benefit of others. This works on 2.6.4.

Depending upon your requirement, you can still obtain the document from other collections during mapreduce. You can declare a [dbref](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/) and get data from your collection. Even though document says $id field needs to be id, I have tried standard mongo queries there and seems to be working. Based on dbref documentation, you can probably point to different DB also though I have not tried it.

Here is one simplified example of my map function where I am getting data from two other collections and don't have any common field names

```
function() {
var values = {
    providerAccount: this,
};

if (!(typeof(this['lastStatusLogId']) === 'undefined')) {

       var v = new Object();
       v["$ref"] = "statuslog";
       v["$id"] = new ObjectId(this['lastStatusLogId']);
       values['lastStatusLog'] = v;
    }

    v = new Object();
    v["$ref"] = "provider";
    v["$id"] = new ObjectId(this.providerId);
    values["provider"] = v;

    emit(this._id, values);
  }
```